# Pull-to-refresh in UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios6, uikit, pull-to-refresh

I want to implement pull-down-to-refresh in a `UICollectionViewController` under iOS 6. This was easy to achieve with a `UITableViewController`, like so:

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(startRefresh:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.refreshControl = refreshControl;
```

The above implements a nice liquid-drop animation as part of a native widget.

As `UICollectionViewController` is a "more evolved" `UITableViewController` one would expect somewhat of a parity of features, but I can't find a reference anywhere to a built-in way to implement this.

1. Is there a simple way to do this that I'm overlooking?
2. Can `UIRefreshControl` be used somehow with `UICollectionViewController` despite the header and docs both stating that it's meant to be used with a table view?

Answer (score 214, accepted):

The answers to both (1) and (2) are yes.

Simply add a `UIRefreshControl` instance as a subview of `.collectionView` and it just works.

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(startRefresh:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.collectionView addSubview:refreshControl];
```

That's it! I wish this had been mentioned in the documentation somewhere, even though sometimes a simple experiment does the trick.

EDIT: this solution won't work if the collection is not big enough to have an active scrollbar. If you add this statement,

```
self.collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
```

then everything works perfectly. This fix taken from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14693598/1633251) on the same topic (referenced in a comment in the other posted answer).

Comment: I have to point out that UIRefreshControl.alloc.init is an abuse of dot notation. Dot notation is meant to convey accessing internal state, whereas bracket notation is meant to convey that you want an object to perform some action.

Comment: Think of it like lazy-loading where the internal state being accessed is an initialized instance. A stretch, but this is better than my initial response which was just going to be ":p". :)

Comment: If you're going to use dot notation here, I prefer UIRefreshControl.new

Comment: How do you control when the spinner stops? I'm using this with a Parse app and the reloadData method inside the refershControlAction but the wheel just keeps spinning for ever. Any idea of what could be happening there?

Comment: @JuanGonzález: Set the control to an iVar, ala `_refreshControl = blah`, then in `startRefresh:`, when the work is done, do a `_refreshControl endRefreshing];`.

Comment: Does not work in iOS7, the spinner doesn't show up. It's transparent it seems.

Comment: the bounce vertical (crucial) can also be set in IB.

Comment: If anyones interested and using Swift, I wrote a quick simple extension for UICollectionViewController for a convenience var for refreshControl. https://gist.github.com/Baza207/f5ff5abf7b8c44e2ffb3

Comment: Please keep in mind, that adding a refreshControl via `addSubview:` may lead to unexpected behaviour. You can see one example when you use section headers (or supplementary views with the `UICollectionView`) - If you scroll while pull-to-refresh is active the insets of the headers are wrong (because they still use the loading indicator as reference). Apple makes some magic with the `refreshControl` property of `UITableView` - which is not available in a `UICollectionView`

Answer (score 18):

I was looking for the same solution, but in Swift. Based on the above answer, I have done the following:

```
let refreshCtrl = UIRefreshControl()
    ...
refreshCtrl.addTarget(self, action: "startRefresh", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
collectionView?.addSubview(refreshCtrl)
```

Not forgetting to:

```
refreshCtrl.endRefreshing()
```

Answer (score 7):

I was using Storyboard and setting `self.collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;` did not work. Selecting the `Bounces` and `Bounces Vertically` does the job for me.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `refreshControl` property has now been added to `UIScrollView` as of iOS 10 so you can set the refresh control directly on collection views.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollview/2127691-refreshcontrol

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [UIRefreshControl new];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshControlAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.collectionView.refreshControl = refreshControl;
```

Answer (score 2):

mjh's answer is correct.

I ran into the issue where if the the `collectionView.contentSize` was not larger then the `collectionView.frame.size`, you can not get the `collectionView` to scroll. You can not set the `contentSize` property either (at least I couldn't).

If it can't scroll, it won't let you do the pull to refresh.

My solution was to subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and overide the method:

```
- (CGSize)collectionViewContentSize
{
    CGFloat height = [super collectionViewContentSize].height;

    // Always returns a contentSize larger then frame so it can scroll and UIRefreshControl will work
    if (height < self.collectionView.bounds.size.height) {
        height = self.collectionView.bounds.size.height + 1;
    }

    return CGSizeMake([super collectionViewContentSize].width, height);
}
```

Comment: You can also do `self.collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;`.

Credit goes to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678727/uirefreshcontrol-on-uicollectionview-only-works-if-the-collection-fills-the-heig).