# Is there a way for the Top View Controller in ECSlidingViewController to know when the sidebar menu has been dismissed?

Tags: ios, ecslidingviewcontroller

Is there a way for the Top View Controller in ECSlidingViewController to know when the sidebar menu has been dismissed, or when it is about to become the focus? i.e. a sort of viewWillAppear equivalent for ECSlidingViewController.  I have a refreshcontrol in my top view controller that starts misbehaving after the sidebar is shown, so I am trying to figure out where I can call endRefreshing on the refreshControl so that the wierdness goes away.  Putting it in viewWillAppear doesn't work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ECSlidingViewController v2.0 does not have notifications, I was able to solve this in the following way.  In the sidebar menu, in ViewWillDisappear I call a new category method on UIViewController called "willGetFocus."  Whenever my topViewController needs to know when it's about to get focus I override willGetFocus in that view Controller like so:

In sidebar menu:

```
 -(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
 {
     [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
     UINavigationController* topViewController =    
        ((UINavigationController*)self.slidingViewController.topViewController);
     [topViewController.visibleViewController willGetFocus];
 }
```

In Top View Controller:

```
-(void) willGetFocus {

    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

New Category:

```
@interface UIViewController (KnowsFocus)

-(void) willGetFocus;

@end

@implementation UIViewController (KnowsFocus)

-(void) willGetFocus {

}
@end
```